# ASM Program that worked a couple of seconds ago - doesn't now

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

Recently started using nasm, saw some sample code for "Hello World":

```
SECTION .TEXT
        GLOBAL _start



_start:
        mov eax, 4            ; 'write' system call = 4
        mov ebx, 1            ; file descriptor 1 = STDOUT
        mov ecx, hello        ; string to write
        mov edx, helloLen     ; length of string to write
        int 0x80              ; call the kernel

        mov eax,1       ; Terminate program
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80

; Define variables in the data section
SECTION .DATA
        hello:     db 'Hello world!',10
        helloLen:  equ $-hello
```

(I called this file `hello.asm`)

However when I compile "assemble" everything using these commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
```

Then

```
 ld -s -o hello hello.o
```

When I enter:

```
./hello
```

It gives me this message: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
I could swear that this program worked for me a couple of seconds ago.. something is completely odd about it and I cannot find the mistake.. I tried removing the piece "Terminate program" because I don't remember seeing this piece before, and it worked just find without it - but the same error appears...

I even saw this video and basically it is the same code..
[John Hammond's video "Hello World" x86 Assembly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgEGAaYdABA&ab_channel=JohnHammond)

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: It's a 32-bit program but you're building it as a 64-bit program?  However, it does work for me.

Comment: @NateEldredge When I change to elf32 (first command) it says: `ld: i386 architecture of input file `hello.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output` Any idea why? it seems strange, I have never encountered in such problems before, everything worked just fine, or else I don't remember correctly..

Comment: Yeah, because the linker is still assuming 64 bit.  Add `-melf_i386` to the `ld` command line.  Very simple 32-bit code may work in 64-bit mode, but not in general.

Comment: @NateEldredge Wait so you're saying that it is not correct to learn nasm 32bit on a 64bit machine? what should I do then? you're saying that only a small portion of programs would work..?

Comment: 32-bit programs will work if you build them as 32-bit programs (`-felf32` and `-melf_i386`), so that they run in 32-bit mode.  32-bit code built as a 64-bit program and run in 64-bit mode is what will rarely work.  But I think it would be a better use of your time to learn 64-bit assembly anyway, as 32-bit is becoming quite obsolete.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm sorry for the massive questions here, I don't feel like it should be a whole question by itself, what is 64 asssembly? I mean, is it TASM or MASM? or is it still NASM but the 64bit "version"? Thank you very much sir.

Comment: nasm is just an assembler, it can assemble either 32 or 64 bit code as desired (see the `BITS` directive).  But you use different instructions in 64-bit mode, e.g. 64-bit registers `rax, rbx, ...` instead of 32-bit `eax, ebx, ...`, different calling conventions, `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`, the ability to use more than 4GB of memory, and so on.

Comment: If you're following a tutorial for 32-bit Linux, you just need to learn the right build commands to use on a 64-bit system to make 32-bit executables.  (And for libc, you might need to install some lib32 or gcc-multilib or whatever your distro calls it).  Do *not* try to port the code itself to work in 64-bit mode until after you've learned whatever the tutorial is trying to teach you.

Comment: Are you sure you saved your source before rebuilding and running?  This source should work fine if built into a 64-bit static executable, assuming your kernel has CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION at all.  That's very much not a recommended way to do things, and you will start to run into stuff that breaks if you assemble code written for 32-bit into 64-bit executables.  e.g. `sub esp, 8` would truncate the 64-bit stack pointer to 32 bits, and make the next push/pop/call segfault.

Comment: @NateEldredge Note that the `BITS` directive is a red herring.  Operation mode is selectd by the output file type and overriding it with the `BITS` directive is usually wrong.